# image filtering - histogram equalization with glsl shaders

Tags: opengl, image-processing, glsl, histogram, imagefilter

I need to implement some image filtering algorithms with glsl. As far as I understand, fragment shader code runs for every texel (pixel) in the image texture. So, implementing point (pixel) based filtering algorithms are easy (e.g. brightness/contrast change, sobel filter etc.). But, for tasks like histogram equalization or finding maximum pixel value in the image traversing all pixels are needed. However, in the shader code doing something like below is not the case.

```
for (int y=0; y<h; y++)
   for (int x=0; x<w; x++)
```

Because, it causes traversing all image data per pixel.
My question is how  one can calculate the image histogram or find the maximum pixel value in the image? Is there any example code or tutorial for this?

Comment: As you're pointing out yourself, fragment shaders are executed locally and don't have access to non-local data if you don't provide it. You'll need to use other execution environments to gather the information you need (compute, opencl)? Another simple way to get some information is to calculate MIP maps so you can do queries with large kernels.

Comment: @orkan Check this link : http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch41.html

Comment: @orkan , I am also trying to implement a similar concept , I am trying adaptive histogram equalization , create image histogram and CLAHE , I am also stuck, did you get any solution?

Comment: @subhfyu546754 hi, you can use opengl compute shaders. check this out: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/180692-OpenGL-Compute-Shaders-vs-OpenCL?p=1246752&viewfull=1#post1246752